# How to generate view from Monthly data in rows converting it to columns in Oracle tables

Tags: sql, oracle, pivot

I have monthly data in Rows but I need data to be transformed by Monthly Columns instead of one consolidated Month column, can you please help here to see if I can create a view from the Target table to group by on Monthly column?

Source

```
Account        DAY  CENTER  ENTITY   YEAR  FREQUENCY       AMOUNT  MONTH
A010100001000  D02  CC124   BBC0181  FY15  PATD       -3185791.08  Jan
A010100001000  D02  CC13L   BBC0181  FY15  PATD        -156955.28  Feb
A010100001000  D02  CC11B   BBC0181  FY15  PATD        -666443.03  Mar
A010100001000  D02  CCR81   BBC0181  FY15  PATD        -178392.23  Apr
A010100001000  D02  CCR82   BBC0181  FY15  PATD        -192553.44  May
A010100001000  D02  CC10M   BBC0181  FY15  PATD        -457125.95  Jun
A010100001000  D02  CC13P   BBC0181  FY15  PATD         -41853.95  Jul
A010100001000  D02  CCR53   BBC0181  FY15  PATD        -110299.8   Aug
A010100001000  D02  CCR54   BBC0181  FY15  PATD        -182933.93  Sep
A010100001000  D02  CC11C   BBC0181  FY15  PATD        -468148.55  Oct
A010100001000  D02  CCR71   BBC0181  FY15  PATD        -133119.11  Nov
A010100001000  D02  CCW4A   BBC0181  FY15  PATD        -201339.86  Dec
```

Desired output

```
Account        DAY  CENTER  ENTITY   YEAR  FREQUENCY          Jan          Feb          Mar          Apr          May          Jun          Jul          Aug          Sep          Oct          Nov          Dec
A010100001000  D02  CC10M   BBC0181  FY15  PATD                                                                         -457125.95                        
A010100001000  D02  CC11B   BBC0181  FY15  PATD                                  -666443.03                                    
A010100001000  D02  CC11C   BBC0181  FY15  PATD                                                                                                                             -468148.55        
A010100001000  D02  CC124   BBC0181  FY15  PATD        -3185791.08                                            
A010100001000  D02  CC13L   BBC0181  FY15  PATD                     -156955.28                                        
A010100001000  D02  CC13P   BBC0181  FY15  PATD                                                                                       -41853.95                    
A010100001000  D02  CCR53   BBC0181  FY15  PATD                                                                                                    -110299.8                
A010100001000  D02  CCR54   BBC0181  FY15  PATD                                                                                                                -182933.93            
A010100001000  D02  CCR71   BBC0181  FY15  PATD                                               -133119.11    
A010100001000  D02  CCR81   BBC0181  FY15  PATD                                                            -178392.23                                
A010100001000  D02  CCR82   BBC0181  FY15  PATD                    -192553.44                            
A010100001000  D02  CCW4A   BBC0181  FY15  PATD                                                                                                                                                       -201339.86
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion Eric, I have updated my question.

Comment: Please post data, expected results and code [as formatted text](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting), and [not as images](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The basic pattern you want is to have a case expression for each month, and only show the amount if the monthmatches:

```
select account, day, center, entity, year, frequency,
  case when month = 'Jan' then amount end as jan,
  case when month = 'Feb' then amount end as feb,
  case when month = 'Mar' then amount end as mar,
-- ... all the other months
  case when month = 'Dec' then amount end as dec
from source;

ACCOUNT       DAY CENTE ENTITY  YEAR FREQ        JAN        FEB        MAR ...        DEC
------------- --- ----- ------- ---- ---- ---------- ---------- ---------- ... ----------
A010100001000 D02 CC124 BBC0181 FY15 PATD -3185791.1
A010100001000 D02 CC13L BBC0181 FY15 PATD            -156955.28
A010100001000 D02 CC11B BBC0181 FY15 PATD                       -666443.03
...
A010100001000 D02 CCW4A BBC0181 FY15 PATD                                  ... -201339.86
```

If you could have more than one entry in a row in your output then it's closer to a normal pivot, but you can still do the same thing with the addition of an aggregate and matching grouping:

```
select account, day, center, entity, year, frequency,
  max(case when month = 'Jan' then amount end) as jan,
  max(case when month = 'Feb' then amount end) as feb,
  max(case when month = 'Mar' then amount end) as mar,
-- ...
  max(case when month = 'Dec' then amount end) as dec
from source
group by account, day, center, entity, year, frequency;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Alex, I really appreciate your here. I can run the query you have provided but the problem is where I have Account, Day, Center, Entity... combination for all months data instead of showing all data in one single row with Monthly separated values it is showing up separately in 12 rows. Can you please let us if we can combine that into one column?

Comment: @Rakesh - that is what the second version is for, using an aggregate (max) to get a value for each month in one row for each combination. It's just a manual pivot.

Comment: Hello Alex, Thanks a lot for your help, the solution you have provided worked as we needed for our automation.

Answer (score 1):

I was going to suggest you to use [PIVOT](https://blogs.oracle.com/sql/how-to-convert-rows-to-columns-and-back-again-with-sql-aka-pivot-and-unpivot), but I see that you wanted them to be individual rows, not all in one row. You could do something like this:

```
SELECT ACCOUNT, DAY, CENTER, ENTITY, YEAR, FREQUENCY, 
CASE WHEN MONTH = 'Jan'
THEN AMOUNT
END "Jan"
CASE WHEN MONTH = 'Feb'
THEN AMOUNT
END "Feb"
.... FROM TABLENAME
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this should work..

```
WITH tmp AS
(
  SELECT 'A010100001000' Account,  'D02' as day,  'CC124' center,   'BBC0181' entity,   'FY15' year,  'PATD' FREQUENCY ,      -3185791.08 amount, 'Jan' mnth FROM dual UNION
  SELECT 'A010100001000',  'D02', 'CC13L', 'BBC0181', 'FY15', 'PATD',        -156955.28,  'Feb'   FROM dual UNION
  SELECT 'A010100001000',  'D02', 'CC11B', 'BBC0181', 'FY15', 'PATD',        -666443.03,  'Mar'   FROM dual UNION
  SELECT 'A010100001000',  'D02', 'CCR81', 'BBC0181', 'FY15', 'PATD',        -178392.23,  'Apr'   FROM dual UNION
  SELECT 'A010100001000',  'D02', 'CCR82', 'BBC0181', 'FY15', 'PATD',        -192553.44,  'May'   FROM dual UNION
  SELECT 'A010100001000',  'D02', 'CC10M', 'BBC0181', 'FY15', 'PATD',        -457125.95,  'Jun'   FROM dual UNION
  SELECT 'A010100001000',  'D02', 'CC13P', 'BBC0181', 'FY15', 'PATD',         -41853.95,  'Jul'   FROM dual UNION
  SELECT 'A010100001000',  'D02', 'CCR53', 'BBC0181', 'FY15', 'PATD',        -110299.8 ,  'Aug'   FROM dual UNION
  SELECT 'A010100001000',  'D02', 'CCR54', 'BBC0181', 'FY15', 'PATD',        -182933.93,  'Sep'   FROM dual UNION
  SELECT 'A010100001000',  'D02', 'CC11C', 'BBC0181', 'FY15', 'PATD',        -468148.55,  'Oct'   FROM dual UNION
  SELECT 'A010100001000',  'D02', 'CCR71', 'BBC0181', 'FY15', 'PATD',        -133119.11,  'Nov'   FROM dual UNION
  SELECT 'A010100001000',  'D02', 'CCW4A', 'BBC0181', 'FY15', 'PATD',        -201339.86,  'Dec'   FROM dual 
)
SELECT 
  * 
FROM tmp
PIVOT
(
  MAX(amount) FOR mnth IN ('Jan' Jan, 'Feb' feb, 'Mar' Mar, 'Apr' Apr, 'May' May, 'Jun' Jun, 'Jul' Jul, 'Aug' Aug, 'Sep' Sep, 'Oct' Oct, 'Nov' Nov, 'Dec' Dec)
);
```